# What determines parquet file buffer sizes

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hdfs, parquet

I wrote a DataFrame in spark-shell into hdfs and I got the below output. What I want to understand is, what determines the size of the parquet files being written? My dfs.block.size is set to:

```
scala> spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.get("dfs.block.size")
res1: String = 134217728
```

which is 128MB, so why are my files in the 20,000,000 range of bytes?

```
-rw-r--r--   1 hadoop supergroup          0 2018-11-13 11:51 /new_sample_parquet_test/_SUCCESS
-rw-r--r--   1 hadoop supergroup   23631191 2018-11-13 11:51 /new_sample_parquet_test/part-00000-18b6439e-ce51-49e3-afac-e93d5cf6de44-c000.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   1 hadoop supergroup   23435545 2018-11-13 11:51 /new_sample_parquet_test/part-00001-18b6439e-ce51-49e3-afac-e93d5cf6de44-c000.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   1 hadoop supergroup   22568091 2018-11-13 11:51 /new_sample_parquet_test/part-00002-18b6439e-ce51-49e3-afac-e93d5cf6de44-c000.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   1 hadoop supergroup   23385544 2018-11-13 11:51 /new_sample_parquet_test/part-00003-18b6439e-ce51-49e3-afac-e93d5cf6de44-c000.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   1 hadoop supergroup   23335676 2018-11-13 11:51 /new_sample_parquet_test/part-00004-18b6439e-ce51-49e3-afac-e93d5cf6de44-c000.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   1 hadoop supergroup   23423372 2018-11-13 11:51 /new_sample_parquet_test/part-00005-18b6439e-ce51-49e3-afac-e93d5cf6de44-c000.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   1 hadoop supergroup   22182760 2018-11-13 11:51 /new_sample_parquet_test/part-00006-18b6439e-ce51-49e3-afac-e93d5cf6de44-c000.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   1 hadoop supergroup   20906453 2018-11-13 11:51 /new_sample_parquet_test/part-00007-18b6439e-ce51-49e3-afac-e93d5cf6de44-c000.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   1 hadoop supergroup   22918107 2018-11-13 11:51 /new_sample_parquet_test/part-00008-18b6439e-ce51-49e3-afac-e93d5cf6de44-c000.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   1 hadoop supergroup   21655224 2018-11-13 11:51 /new_sample_parquet_test/part-00009-18b6439e-ce51-49e3-afac-e93d5cf6de44-c000.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   1 hadoop supergroup   20366872 2018-11-13 11:51 /new_sample_parquet_test/part-00010-18b6439e-ce51-49e3-afac-e93d5cf6de44-c000.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   1 hadoop supergroup   22658141 2018-11-13 11:51 /new_sample_parquet_test/part-00011-18b6439e-ce51-49e3-afac-e93d5cf6de44-c000.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   1 hadoop supergroup   22246580 2018-11-13 11:51 /new_sample_parquet_test/part-00012-18b6439e-ce51-49e3-afac-e93d5cf6de44-c000.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   1 hadoop supergroup   20648612 2018-11-13 11:51 /new_sample_parquet_test/part-00013-18b6439e-ce51-49e3-afac-e93d5cf6de44-c000.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   1 hadoop supergroup   22369663 2018-11-13 11:51 /new_sample_parquet_test/part-00014-18b6439e-ce51-49e3-afac-e93d5cf6de44-c000.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   1 hadoop supergroup   23396027 2018-11-13 11:51 /new_sample_parquet_test/part-00015-18b6439e-ce51-49e3-afac-e93d5cf6de44-c000.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   1 hadoop supergroup   23382811 2018-11-13 11:51 /new_sample_parquet_test/part-00016-18b6439e-ce51-49e3-afac-e93d5cf6de44-c000.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   1 hadoop supergroup   17470540 2018-11-13 11:51 /new_sample_parquet_test/part-00017-18b6439e-ce51-49e3-afac-e93d5cf6de44-c000.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   1 hadoop supergroup   22669018 2018-11-13 11:51 /new_sample_parquet_test/part-00018-18b6439e-ce51-49e3-afac-e93d5cf6de44-c000.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   1 hadoop supergroup   21899425 2018-11-13 11:51 /new_sample_parquet_test/part-00019-18b6439e-ce51-49e3-afac-e93d5cf6de44-c000.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   1 hadoop supergroup   21378060 2018-11-13 11:51 /new_sample_parquet_test/part-00020-18b6439e-ce51-49e3-afac-e93d5cf6de44-c000.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   1 hadoop supergroup   21578176 2018-11-13 11:51 /new_sample_parquet_test/part-00021-18b6439e-ce51-49e3-afac-e93d5cf6de44-c000.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   1 hadoop supergroup   21079291 2018-11-13 11:51 /new_sample_parquet_test/part-00022-18b6439e-ce51-49e3-afac-e93d5cf6de44-c000.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   1 hadoop supergroup   21526313 2018-11-13 11:51 /new_sample_parquet_test/part-00023-18b6439e-ce51-49e3-afac-e93d5cf6de44-c000.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   1 hadoop supergroup   22446489 2018-11-13 11:51 /new_sample_parquet_test/part-00024-18b6439e-ce51-49e3-afac-e93d5cf6de44-c000.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   1 hadoop supergroup   21770955 2018-11-13 11:51 /new_sample_parquet_test/part-00025-18b6439e-ce51-49e3-afac-e93d5cf6de44-c000.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   1 hadoop supergroup   23199003 2018-11-13 11:51 /new_sample_parquet_test/part-00026-18b6439e-ce51-49e3-afac-e93d5cf6de44-c000.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   1 hadoop supergroup   21833916 2018-11-13 11:51 /new_sample_parquet_test/part-00027-18b6439e-ce51-49e3-afac-e93d5cf6de44-c000.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   1 hadoop supergroup   25090443 2018-11-13 11:51 /new_sample_parquet_test/part-00028-18b6439e-ce51-49e3-afac-e93d5cf6de44-c000.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   1 hadoop supergroup   20725755 2018-11-13 11:51 /new_sample_parquet_test/part-00029-18b6439e-ce51-49e3-afac-e93d5cf6de44-c000.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   1 hadoop supergroup   20666565 2018-11-13 11:51 /new_sample_parquet_test/part-00030-18b6439e-ce51-49e3-afac-e93d5cf6de44-c000.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   1 hadoop supergroup   22299474 2018-11-13 11:51 /new_sample_parquet_test/part-00031-18b6439e-ce51-49e3-afac-e93d5cf6de44-c000.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   1 hadoop supergroup   22327133 2018-11-13 11:51 /new_sample_parquet_test/part-00032-18b6439e-ce51-49e3-afac-e93d5cf6de44-c000.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   1 hadoop supergroup   22207468 2018-11-13 11:51 /new_sample_parquet_test/part-00033-18b6439e-ce51-49e3-afac-e93d5cf6de44-c000.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   1 hadoop supergroup   22630251 2018-11-13 11:51 /new_sample_parquet_test/part-00034-18b6439e-ce51-49e3-afac-e93d5cf6de44-c000.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   1 hadoop supergroup   21648270 2018-11-13 11:51 /new_sample_parquet_test/part-00035-18b6439e-ce51-49e3-afac-e93d5cf6de44-c000.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   1 hadoop supergroup   22230127 2018-11-13 11:51 /new_sample_parquet_test/part-00036-18b6439e-ce51-49e3-afac-e93d5cf6de44-c000.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   1 hadoop supergroup   22439910 2018-11-13 11:51 /new_sample_parquet_test/part-00037-18b6439e-ce51-49e3-afac-e93d5cf6de44-c000.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   1 hadoop supergroup   22252551 2018-11-13 11:51 /new_sample_parquet_test/part-00038-18b6439e-ce51-49e3-afac-e93d5cf6de44-c000.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   1 hadoop supergroup   22160655 2018-11-13 11:51 /new_sample_parquet_test/part-00039-18b6439e-ce51-49e3-afac-e93d5cf6de44-c000.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   1 hadoop supergroup   17637580 2018-11-13 11:51 /new_sample_parquet_test/part-00040-18b6439e-ce51-49e3-afac-e93d5cf6de44-c000.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   1 hadoop supergroup   21743969 2018-11-13 11:51 /new_sample_parquet_test/part-00041-18b6439e-ce51-49e3-afac-e93d5cf6de44-c000.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   1 hadoop supergroup   22071235 2018-11-13 11:51 /new_sample_parquet_test/part-00042-18b6439e-ce51-49e3-afac-e93d5cf6de44-c000.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   1 hadoop supergroup   21854771 2018-11-13 11:51 /new_sample_parquet_test/part-00043-18b6439e-ce51-49e3-afac-e93d5cf6de44-c000.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   1 hadoop supergroup   25243330 2018-11-13 11:51 /new_sample_parquet_test/part-00044-18b6439e-ce51-49e3-afac-e93d5cf6de44-c000.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   1 hadoop supergroup   22297865 2018-11-13 11:51 /new_sample_parquet_test/part-00045-18b6439e-ce51-49e3-afac-e93d5cf6de44-c000.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   1 hadoop supergroup   22070057 2018-11-13 11:51 /new_sample_parquet_test/part-00046-18b6439e-ce51-49e3-afac-e93d5cf6de44-c000.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   1 hadoop supergroup   22018671 2018-11-13 11:51 /new_sample_parquet_test/part-00047-18b6439e-ce51-49e3-afac-e93d5cf6de44-c000.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   1 hadoop supergroup   21796749 2018-11-13 11:51 /new_sample_parquet_test/part-00048-18b6439e-ce51-49e3-afac-e93d5cf6de44-c000.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   1 hadoop supergroup   22597634 2018-11-13 11:51 /new_sample_parquet_test/part-00049-18b6439e-ce51-49e3-afac-e93d5cf6de44-c000.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   1 hadoop supergroup   20728588 2018-11-13 11:51 /new_sample_parquet_test/part-00050-18b6439e-ce51-49e3-afac-e93d5cf6de44-c000.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   1 hadoop supergroup   22137701 2018-11-13 11:51 /new_sample_parquet_test/part-00051-18b6439e-ce51-49e3-afac-e93d5cf6de44-c000.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   1 hadoop supergroup   22387635 2018-11-13 11:51 /new_sample_parquet_test/part-00052-18b6439e-ce51-49e3-afac-e93d5cf6de44-c000.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   1 hadoop supergroup   20965957 2018-11-13 11:51 /new_sample_parquet_test/part-00053-18b6439e-ce51-49e3-afac-e93d5cf6de44-c000.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   1 hadoop supergroup   20314451 2018-11-13 11:51 /new_sample_parquet_test/part-00054-18b6439e-ce51-49e3-afac-e93d5cf6de44-c000.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   1 hadoop supergroup   22538965 2018-11-13 11:51 /new_sample_parquet_test/part-00055-18b6439e-ce51-49e3-afac-e93d5cf6de44-c000.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   1 hadoop supergroup   20923261 2018-11-13 11:51 /new_sample_parquet_test/part-00056-18b6439e-ce51-49e3-afac-e93d5cf6de44-c000.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   1 hadoop supergroup   20984805 2018-11-13 11:51 /new_sample_parquet_test/part-00057-18b6439e-ce51-49e3-afac-e93d5cf6de44-c000.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   1 hadoop supergroup   20513317 2018-11-13 11:51 /new_sample_parquet_test/part-00058-18b6439e-ce51-49e3-afac-e93d5cf6de44-c000.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   1 hadoop supergroup   25493903 2018-11-13 11:51 /new_sample_parquet_test/part-00059-18b6439e-ce51-49e3-afac-e93d5cf6de44-c000.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   1 hadoop supergroup   21178862 2018-11-13 11:51 /new_sample_parquet_test/part-00060-18b6439e-ce51-49e3-afac-e93d5cf6de44-c000.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   1 hadoop supergroup   20696540 2018-11-13 11:51 /new_sample_parquet_test/part-00061-18b6439e-ce51-49e3-afac-e93d5cf6de44-c000.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   1 hadoop supergroup   21011416 2018-11-13 11:51 /new_sample_parquet_test/part-00062-18b6439e-ce51-49e3-afac-e93d5cf6de44-c000.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r--   1 hadoop supergroup   15752503 2018-11-13 11:51 /new_sample_parquet_test/part-00063-18b6439e-ce51-49e3-afac-e93d5cf6de44-c000.snappy.parquet
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parquet writer is not concerned with HDFS block size as you can save parquet e.g. on a local hard drive. What determines the number and sizes of individual part-*.parquet files is the number of partitions in your data frame (64 in your case). If you would do  `df.coalesce(1).write.parquet(...)`, you'll have just one large part file.

If you want the part files to be around 128 Mb each, coalesce parameter should be around 20 * 64 / 128 = 10. The part file size for a given number of coalesced partitions dependency is not strictly linear though. The smaller the number of part files, the more efficient encoding/compression is.

See [coalesce](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset@coalesce(numPartitions:Int):org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[T]) method description for details

Comment: I'm a little confused. Is it not true that there is one hdfs block per file? Also, there is only one partition in the data, so I still don't get why it became so many small files. This isn't implying that there is one file per partition is it?

Comment: >  Is it not true that there is one hdfs block per file? 
Of course there may be multiple blocks per file, otherwise how would you store, say 1 Gb file? 
> Also, there is only one partition in the data
Are you sure you only have a single partition? What df.rdd.getNumPartitions shows for your DF?